# trying to make a sticky header stick on page load, before scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have this header that is working fine. My issue is that when you reload the page when the scroll position is passed 114, the header is not fixed until you scroll. I'm trying to get it to detect the scroll position of the page before the user scrolls.

```
function initHeader() {
  var Header = document.querySelector(".header");

  var HeaderContainer = document.querySelector(".header-container-after");

  document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        if (window.scrollY > 114) {
            Header.classList.add('header--is-fixed');
            HeaderContainer.classList.add('fixed-header-container');
        } else {
            Header.classList.remove('header--is-fixed');
            HeaderContainer.classList.remove('fixed-header-container');
        }

  });
}

window.onload = initHeader;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be an even easier solution, use `position: sticky; top: 0`
It will act as an relative element until it hits the top (or before, change the top value) and from that point it will act as a fixed element.

In case you want to stick with JS for this, wrap it in a function and call it on load

```
let header;
let headerContainer;

function fixNav(){
  if (window.scrollY > 114) {
            header.classList.add('header--is-fixed');
            headerContainer.classList.add('fixed-header-container');
        } else {
            header.classList.remove('header--is-fixed');
            headerContainer.classList.remove('fixed-header-container');
        }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  header = document.querySelector(".header");
  headerContainer = document.querySelector(".header-container-after");

  document.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);  
  fixNav();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are only running the code when the user scrolls. Try running it when the user scrolls AND when the page loads. Like so:

```
function initHeader() {
  var Header = document.querySelector(".header");

  var HeaderContainer = document.querySelector(".header-container-after");

  // extract the logic to a function
  var updateNav = function () {
      if (window.scrollY > 114) {
          Header.classList.add('header--is-fixed');
          HeaderContainer.classList.add('fixed-header-container');
      } else {
          Header.classList.remove('header--is-fixed');
          HeaderContainer.classList.remove('fixed-header-container');
      }
  }

  // run that function on scroll
  document.addEventListener('scroll', updateNav);
  // but also run it right now (page load)
  updateNav();
}

window.onload = initHeader;
```